# git-tfs: Unable to clone TFS project

Tags: tfvc, git-tfs

I am trying to use git-tfs to clone a TFVC repository, using this command line.

```
C:\<subfolder>>git tfs clone http://<server>:8080/tfs/<collection> $/Project/SubFolder/Project
Found matching Visual Studio version at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/<subfolder>/Project/.git/
```

However, this results in the following error message:

```
Fetching from TFS remote 'default'...
error: a problem occurred when trying to clone the repository. Try to solve the problem described below.
In any case, after, try to continue using command `git tfs fetch`

One or more errors occurred.
Unable to get artifacts from tool.
RebuildCallersViews: Connecting Domain User could not be validated. ---> RebuildCallersViews: Connecting Domain User could not be validated. ---> RebuildCallersViews: Connecting Domain User could not be validated.
All the logs could be found in the log file: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\git-tfs\git-tfs_log.txt
All the logs could be found in the log file: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\git-tfs\git-tfs_log.txt
```

This would appear to be a permissions issue. Can anyone advise as to which permissions are needed for the clone operation?

Comment: The user that you use should have access to the tfvc source code.

Comment: @Philippe I do. I can clone this project with git-tf but not git-tfs.

Comment: In the end, the git-tfs alternative git-tf was the solution. We never did determine the issue with git-tfs and this repo.